# How to view yearly data on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have set up Google Analytics on my website and I have made it work.

A few months later, I realize that I want to see the data from the very start (when I set it up), until now (3 months later).

Currently, I can only see Hourly, Daily, Weekly, and Monthly views.

[image]

**Is there a way for me to view yearly data?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this :**

[image]

It's working for me.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I didn't see the custom date range setter until you showed me this.